# Code Analysis Warning 2214 - How best to fix?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    public partial class AuditLog : IBusinessEntity
    {
        public BusinessEntityType EntityType { get { return BusinessEntityType.AuditLog; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor accepting parameter initialization arguments
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        /// <param name="commandText"></param>
        public AuditLog(string userName, BusinessEntityType entity, AuditLogCommand command, string commandText)
        {
            this.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            this.UserName = userName;
            this.Entity = entity.ToString();
            this.Command = command.ToString();
            this.CommandText = commandText;
        }
    }
```

This is generating a CA2214 warning. The `BusinessEntityType` and `AuditLogCommand` method parameters are both enumerations. I don't see what the issue is here, and therefore am not certain how to satisfy the warning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is one or more of your properties virtual ? Then that is why, since [CA2214 is the "Do not call overridable methods in constructors"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx) warning.

Here is the reasoning for the rule from MSDN:

> When a virtual method is called, the
>   actual type that executes the method
>   is not selected until run time. When a
>   constructor calls a virtual method, it
>   is possible that the constructor for
>   the instance that invokes the method
>   has not executed.

What this *means* is that if someone inherits from your class, and overrides a method or property that is accessed in *your* constructor - then the overriding implementation will be hit before the constructor for the inherited class has run. This might lead to problems if the overriding implementation relies on state set in the constructor.

To satisfy the warning, you  need to make the properties and methods accessed in the constructor non-virtual (you could make the type sealed, if appropiate).

Comment: As it turns out the 'this.Entity' line has a setter that calls a virtual method. I guess that was the issue.

Comment: Yes, the warning will fire if the static analyzer can see, that any virtual method is called during the ctor.